# how to get the parent category services with children category also services of children category in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I trying to get main category services and children category service providing
main category id
and
I have tried this on I get result with all service and children services but I want them into one array how can I do this ?

```
public function serviceswithChildrenCategory($id)
{
    $category = Category::where('id',$id)->with('services') 
    ->with(['childrens' => function($query) use ($id) {  
        $query->with('services'); 
    }])->get(); 

    return $category;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dot` notation to get all posts that have at least one `services` that has at least one `childrens`:

```
$category = Category::where('id',$id)
   ->with(['services','services.childrens'])
   ->get();
```

Check the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#nested-eager-loading) for more information.

Comment: Hey matiaslauriti, Thanks for the reply I don't want services children actually I want the main category along with sub-category's services in an array. thanks again.